# Loop through categories and create tab for each

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories

I'm trying to create a page that holds all categories of my custom post type as tabs, with a tab content.

I am able to display all the category names as tabs, but i need to run a query in each tab content area to the corresponding category.

So when I click on tab named "1" the tab content area should only show posts from the category belonging to the tab named "1".

My code so far:

```
  <?php
echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';

 $args = array(
 'hide_empty'=> 1,
 'orderby' => 'name',
 'order' => 'ASC'
 );

$categories = get_categories($args);

  foreach($categories as $category) { 

    echo '<li><a href="#' . $category->name.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' .      
    $category->name.'</a></li>';
    $cat_name = $category->name;

    } 
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<div class="tab-content">';
      foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="' . $category->name.'">';


        ?>

 <?php 

     $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'acme_product',
      'posts_per_page' => 100,
      'category_name' => $category->slug
        )); 
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
     $the_query->the_post();
     ?>

            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                   <?php 
    endwhile; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>   


    <?php } 
    echo '</div>';
     ?>
```

The problems is that each content area displays all post of every category.

The html ouput:

```
   <div class="container">

               <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"><li><a href="#Audi" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Audi</a></li><li><a href="#Skoda" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Skoda</a></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane" id="Audi">

        <h1>fffffffffffff</h1>




<div class="tab-pane" id="Skoda">

        <h1>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</h1>




</div>                       
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `'category_name' => $category->slug` instead of `'category_name' => $cat_name`.

You are also missing `wp_reset_postdata();` just after `endwhile;`.

Comment: I've added `wp_reset_postdata();` and changede name to slug. I'm still getting all the posts under each tab. As I understand it this should add the post from the category in question for each category. I'm banging my head here.

Comment: I made an update to my answer. I noticed another small bug that would simply repeat the same category. Though that doesn't explain why it loads all posts. Could you link us to the output?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working on local host, so I can't provide a link. I also applied your changes. Still no dice.

Comment: Can you edit you question and post the html output?

Comment: It turned out to be a missing closing tag. I can't believe I wasted 5 hours on this. I'm sorry for wasting your time - and I appreciate your help. Thx alot!

Answer (score 2):

Try This code

```
<?php
echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';
$args = array(
    'hide_empty'=> 1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo 
        '<li>
            <a href="#'.$category->slug.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">    
                '.$category->name.'
            </a>
        </li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

echo '<div class="tab-content">';
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="' . $category->slug.'">';
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'acme_product',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'category_name' => $category->slug
    ));

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<h1>';
        the_title();
    echo '</h1>';
    endwhile;

    echo '</div>';
} 
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: hi! i edited the code the arranged in nice format i'm only add $category->slug to some part of the code i'm sure this code work 100/100 i use it in my navbar tab

Comment: Please explain _in your answer_ (not in a comment), what your code does and why it works.

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php
echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'annualreports_category',
    'hide_empty'=>0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo 
        '<li>
            <span data-href="'.$category->slug.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">    
                '.$category->name.'
            </span>
        </li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

echo '<div class="investors-content">';
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="' . $category->slug.'">';
    $catslug = $category->slug;
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'annualreports_post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'annualreports_category',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => array( $catslug ),
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        ),
                    ),
    ));                 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<h1>';
        the_title();
        echo '</h1>';
    endwhile; 
    echo '</div>';
} 
echo '</div>';
?>
```

jQuery

```js
$(".investors-content .tab-pane").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.investors-content .tab-pane:first-child()').show();
});

$('.nav-tabs li>span').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $(".investors-content .tab-pane").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        if($(this).attr('id') == id) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```